# Jenkins - Running concurrent jobs with "circular" parameter

Tags: jenkins

I'd like to run several builds concurrently in Jenkins for the same job. I run at maximum 3 builds concurrently. I want each build to run with a parameter that must be unique from a pool for parameters. For instance, pool=[1, 2, 3]: The 1st build picks "1", 2nd picks "2" and the 3rd picks "3".

**I must ensure that different builds can't pick the same parameter.**

**After building, the parameter is available again.**

How can I do it?

*Alternative:* How can I count the number of builds running in this project and pass it as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

At first, select the checkbox button named `build-concurrently-if-neccesary` to ensure the same job could build concurrently. you'd better read the help-html seriously before

The isolated environments for building different jobs make that data could not be shared each other in a simple way.

Here is a solution that trigger the `buildWithParameters` link by **jenkins rest api** to control the pool in the program procedure of your own.

> 1. add a string-parameter in job's config.
> 2. post the string parameter to `http://$JENKINS_SERVER_URL/job/$JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters`

Maybe it's the most convenient way if no available plugin found.

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin in github and asked the author to publish it. It works well and solves my problem.

[Jenkins Parameter Pool Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameter+Pool+Plugin)